# How to run Cordova application under WebStorm?

Tags: cordova, webstorm

I have created Cordova application with a wizard

[image]

it have created project and some files. Then I have selected run configuration

[image]

and pressed `Debug`.

Nothing happened. No window appeared nowhere, no any signs of something running appeared in `IDE`, no any error messages appeared anywhere.

What I forgot to do / did wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging cordova applications is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-14781](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14781) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: but I have no "running" too, probably my problem is different

Comment: what problems running it have you faced? Just press **OK** to save your configuration, then, having it selected in run configurations dropdown, press **Run** button

Comment: I did, but nothing happened

Comment: no Run console opened, etc.? You must have done smth wrong. please provide screenshots that show your steps

Comment: screenshots are above, no other steps attended; I think program should not just do nothing silently when something goes wrong; if I did something wrong, it should provide error message

Comment: it's just a screenshot of run configuration, and it looks as it should. Normally WebStorm does show a message if smth goes wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket - you will then be able to provide information (logs, videos) needed to see what's going on